# remove multiple character in big file using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to remove multiple character from big text file (around 1GB). The file contains roughly like this:

```
>chr1
NNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNATGGGGA
NNNNNNNNNNNNN
AGCGTAGGCGACG

>chr2
NNNNNNNNNNNNN
ATGCGTAGCGCAT
NNNNNNNNGCATG
CGATGCTAGctag
cgatcgagcgatg
```

I want to get only the 'ATCG' character and want to concatenate all the string so it should look like this:

```
ATGGGGAAGCGTAGGCGACGATGCGTAGCGCATGCATGCGATGCTAGCTAGCGATCGAGCGATG
```

Unfortunately, all the unwanted characters were changed into whitespace just like this:

```
ATGGGGA


AGCGTAGGCGACG


ATGCGTAGCGCAT
```

Am I missing something? This is my code:

```
open FH, "<", 'filename' or die "Can't open\n"; #read the file

while (my $load = sysread (FH, $temp, 1e+8)) {
    warn "Read $load bytes\n";

    $temp =~ s/>chr+//gi;
    $temp =~ s/\d+//g;
    $temp =~ s/n+//gi;

    chomp($temp);
    $process .= uc($temp);
    $temp = '';
}

open (FH, ">", 'newfile') or die "Can't create\n"; #processed string in new file

print FH $process;
close FH;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're stripping characters but you're not touching line feeds. I assume that's what you were trying with:

```
s/n+//g;
```

That needs to be `\n`. `chomp` won't do the trick - that only removes the linefeed at the end of line.

```
s/chr+//g;
```

is also not going to be doing what you wanted - that's literally `ch` then `one or more instances of "r"`.

Given your file has linefeeds in it, is there any particular reason why you need to read the whole lot in one go? I'd be suggesting:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open ( my $input, "<", "input_file_name" ) or die $!;
open ( my $output, ">", "output_file_name" ) or die $!;
while ( my $line = <$input> ) {
    next if $line =~ m/^>/; 
    $line =~ s/[^ATCG]//gi; 
    print {$output} $line;   #NB - no linefeeds at all. 
}

close ( $input );
close ( $output );
```

Gives:

```
ATGGGGAAGCGTAGGCGACGATGCGTAGCGCATGCATGCGATGCTAGCTAG
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure what do you mean by read 'the whole lot in go'. I'm read the file by chuck as the file is very big. I realise that your code only able to extract "ATGC". How about "atgc"? I'm sorry forgot to include lower case as well.

Comment: Yes, but you're doing it via sysread of a number of bytes, which doesn't seem relevant to your needs. I do uppercase because your sample was all uppercase. If you want lower as well, then use `s/^[ATCG]//ig` (and use `uc` again)

Comment: The `s/^[ATCG]//ig` able to extract all the lower cases but it also extract 'c' in '>chr1'. How can I remove '>chr1' ?

Comment: Something like: `s/>chr\d+//g`

Comment: I agree that this is the best way. A simple `next if /^>/` will get rid of the `chr99` labels. Also, there is no need for the `chomp` as the substitute will remove it. It may be better to write that as `tr/ATCGatcg//cd`

Comment: See, I knew I did line oriented for a reason. And 'skipping' lines with `next` was it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is

```
tr -cd ATCG < input > output
```

See [tr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr). Or in perl

```
perl -pe'y/ATCG//cd' input > output
```

See [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-p*) documentation for `-pe` meaning and [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr%2fSEARCHLIST%2fREPLACEMENTLIST%2fcdsr) for `y//` and `cd` modificators.